# Using redux action creators in useEffect hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-hooks, use-effect

I want to use `useEffect` to fire 2 functions (which are redux actions creators) - one function when component mounts, and the other one on unmount, like so:

```
// ...

function MyComp(props) {
  function handleSelectItem(itemId) {
    const data = props.data.filter(/* some filter logic depending on itemId */);
    props.selectItem({ itemId, data });
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    handleSelectItem(1);
    return props.deselectItem;
  }, []);
}

export default connect(null, {selectItem, deselectItem})(MyComp)
```

It works, but the `react-hooks/exhaustive-deps` eslint rule telling me that my `useEffect` has 2 dependencies which I **should** include into the dependencies array (useEffect's second argument) or remove the array completely. Second option is not suitable as I don't need these functions to be called on each render. Hence, I need to include them both. There is an [article](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#is-it-safe-to-omit-functions-from-the-list-of-dependencies) regarding including functions into dependency array. Things described there is pretty much clear to me, but I still confused about the redux action creators in dependencies array  and how react will shallowly compare this functions. For me this is a little bit hard to understand. What is the right way to resolve this particular case what is the right way to use redux action creators in useEffect in general?

Comment: Possible Duplicate of [How do I fix missing dependency in React Hook useEffect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55840294/how-do-i-fix-missing-dependency-in-react-hook-useeffect/55854902#55854902)

Comment: Do you need to use `handleSelectItem` not only in `useEffect`? If not, @ShubhamKhatri gives you a link with the answer. If you need to use `handleSelectItem` in other places, I will write an answer.

Comment: @AndriiGolubenko in my case, `handleSelectItem` is a click event handler. It will execute on each item click (with item id parameter passed in). But also I need to have this event handler fired when component mounts, with a particular `itemId` as a parameter. Answering you question - yes, I need to use it in other places.